# "No Credentials" error thrown when trying to access user settings in AWS through React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services

I’m trying to make a system in React where users can log in and change their credentials. I’m also trying to allow for users to save a profile picture. Whenever they upload a picture, it appears on the settings page but I can’t seem to find a way to fetch it again. To save the image file, this is what I’m using.

```
Storage.put("profile.png", file, {
  contentType: "image/png"
})
```

And then I use `Storage.get("profile.png")` to fetch the image. The problem is when I try to fetch the image, I get an error thrown that says “No Credentials” and in the console, I see a message that says “cannot get guest credentials when mandatory signin enabled.” I also get the same “No Credentials” error thrown when I try to save the image. Does anyone know what’s going on? Here’s the code I used for saving and retrieving the image.

```
  onProcessFile = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    try {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      setImage(reader.result)
    };
    const { id } = await Auth.currentUserPoolUser();
    Storage.put("profile.png", file, {
      contentType: "image/png"
    })
      .then(result => console.log(result))
      .catch(err => alert(err));
  };
```

```
  getCurrentUser = async () => {
    Storage.get("profile.png")
    .then(url => {
      var myRequest = new Request(url);
      fetch(myRequest).then(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          setImage(url)
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => alert(err));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you would need to set the right credentials on your bucket to be able to fetch the images when the user is signed in. Here is a link that goes a little deeper into this subject. [Set up bucket credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-policy.html)